# How to read one column data as one by one row in csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Here I have a dataset with three inputs. Three inputs x1,x2,x3. Here I want to read just x2 column and in that column data stepwise row by row.

Here I wrote a code. But it is just showing only letters.

Here is my code

```
data = pd.read_csv('data6.csv')
row_num =0
x=[]
for col in data:
if (row_num==1):
    x.append(col[0])
row_num =+ 1
print(x)
```

result : `x1,x2,x3`

What I expected output is:

```html
expected output x2 (read one by one row)
65
32
14
25
85
47
63
21
98
65
21
47
48
49
46
43
48
25
28
29
37
```

Subset of my csv file :

```
x1  x2  x3
6   65  78
5   32  59
5   14  547
6   25  69
7   85  57
8   47  51
9   63  26
3   21  38
2   98  24
7   65  96
1   21  85
5   47  94
9   48  15
4   49  27
3   46  96
6   43  32
5   48  10
8   25  75
5   28  20
2   29  30
7   37  96
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Comment: Try `data = pd.read_csv('data6.csv', usecols=['x2'])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want list from `x2` use:

```
x = data['x2'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I even get what you're trying to do from your code.
What you're doing (after fixing the indentation to make it somewhat correct):

- Iterate through all columns of your dataframe
- Take the first character of the column name if `row_num` is equal to 1.

Based on this guess:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("data6.csv")
row_num = 0
x = []
for col in data:
    if row_num == 1:
        x.append(col[0])
    row_num = +1
print(x)
```

What you probably want to do:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("data6.csv")
# Make a list containing the values in column 'x2'
x = list(data['x2'])

# Print all values at once:
print(x)

# Print one value per line:
for val in x:
    print(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using pandas you can use it. You can try this to get any specific column values by using list to direct convert into a list.For loop not needed

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data6.csv')
print(list(data['x2']))
```